# How do people build large collections of bricks?

Tags: technic, shopping

How have people built up such large collections of bricks?

I would like to get into building Lego Great Ball Contraption modules, but this needs a lot of parts to play with. I've got some Lego from (30ish) years ago, but not much seems to have survived, and I've bought a couple of bug Technics sets - but I need a lot more Technics, plus more standard bricks, plates, smooth plates etc.

Buying sets is one way, but expensive and I don't like to just make them and then instantly dismantle again.

Buying on a site like Bricklink is great for specific pieces, or when I have something to get it all in the same colour etc.

I've seen random "1Kg lego parts" on ebay which I can try to use that to build up a load - has anyone tried this?

Or is there another way I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I keep my eye on Craigslist and Facebook Martketplace. There’s always someone selling a collection or a bucket of pieces. There’s also a subreddit /r/legomarketplace that sometimes has good deals. I’ve had success with all of these this year and have put together a great supply of parts and sets.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to buy a load but Facebook marketplace seems to have more choice these days for local heavy items for collection. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, for bulk bricks the best place is eBay.

For greater selection (probably what you need for largish pieces),

- Facebook marketplace
- Craigslist
- Brick-and-mortar stores like https://bricksandminifigs.com/

For individual pieces, Pick-A-Brick or Bricklink.

Also for several months now, Costco has been selling a 1500-piece Creator box for ~$40 which is as good as I've ever seen for new bricks.

Answer (score 0):

Find a teenager you already know who will spread the word that you will trade old, boring Lego collections for new, shiny video game cash.

Their parents will HATE you.